# Repeat a file content until reach a defined line count

Tags: bash

Have a file such the next `file.txt`

```
line-01
line-02
line-03
line-04
line-05
line-06
line-07
line-08
line-09
line-10
```

This contains 10 uniform lines, the real files has different content and different linecounts.

Need repeat the content of this file, util  reaching a defined line count.

Tried the next script:

```
repcat() {
    while :
    do
        cat $1
    done
}

repcat file.txt | head -20
```

It works, prints 20 lines, but never ends, need terminate with CTRL-C.

Why the `repcat` continues to write into the pipe, in a case nobody reading its result?

To be more strange, adding one `echo` after the `cat`

```
repcat() {
        while :
        do
                cat $1
                echo xxx
        done
}

repcat file.txt | head -20
```

the script ends.

Doesn't understand why such  behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `cat` gets an error writing to the pipe, it simply exits, and the script continues to the next loop. Try checking whether `cat` succeeds:

```
repcat() {
    while cat "$1"
    do 
        :
    done
}
```

The reason it works with the additional `echo` is because `echo` is a shell built-in. When it gets an error it terminates the function.

Comment: Yes, it works. And can you explain why the additional `echo` helps?

Comment: Now it is working - thank you very much. Only wondering, is here another way to achieve this? mean without a function and the while cycle?

Comment: You could use something like `awk` to read all the lines into an array, then print them in a loop until you reach the line count.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use:

```
yes "$(< file.txt)" | head -n 20
```

Comment: Work only with files not bigger as 256kb (arg list length - at least on my system) - but this is usually not problem... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach:

```
rephead () { 
    local n=$1; shift        
    if (($# > 0)); then
        input=$(cat "$@")
    else
        input=$(cat -)
    fi
    local lines=$(wc -l <<< "$input")
    local count=0
    while ((count < n)); do
        echo "$input"
        ((count += lines))
    done | head -n $n
}
```

Test:

```
$ seq 3 | rephead 10
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
```

and with files

```
$ cat f1
one
two 
three
four
$ cat f2
a
b
c
d
$ rephead 10 f1 f2
one
two
three
four
a
b
c
d
one
two
```

Comment: An improvement would be to use `getopts` to call it as `rephead -n 10 ...`