# Bash construction $(< file)

Tags: bash

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22820092/869025) I saw the next Bash construction.

```
yes "$(< file.txt)"
```

Whats mean the

```
"$(< file.txt)"  ?
```

I understand

- the command substitution - the `$(command)` is repaced with the result of the command.
- the quotes ensure than the content is not formatted to one line and remains in a form as is in the file

While experimentd with the above, the  next commands gives the same result too.

```
yes "$(cat file.txt)"
```

This one is clear. The `yes` gets as argument the content of the file.

but don't understand those.

```
yes "$(< <(cat file.txt))
yes "$(< file.txt)"
```

especially the last one. What command is substituted in the `$(< file.txt)` ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `< file` is basically reading a file.
- `$(< file.txt)` is basically reading content of file in a string using `$(...)` construct
- `cat` is an external command that causes BASH to fork a subshell if used in `$(...)`

As per [man bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution):

> The command substitution `$(cat file)` can be replaced by the equivalent but faster `$(< file)`.

Comment: I saw the edit but didn't understand what the question is about heredoc?

Comment: Sure that is always better :)

Answer (score 3):

The `$(< file.txt)` syntax is substitution and allows to read file contents without creating a new subshell as in case of `$(cat file.txt)`

Comment: creating a new subshell *and* spawning the external `cat` executable.

Comment: @glennjackman yes, you are right, in total, two additional subprocesses